# Jboss 7 vs Jboss 4

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I found [this great tutorial](http://devbank.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/jaas-authentication-with-jboss-form-based-tutorial-part1/) for JAAS with JBoss, but the problem is that it is an older version. In this tutorial to define application authentication policy at JBoss you need to use "login-config.xml" in this directory -> D:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\mmazharhassan.com\conf\login-config.xml which doesn't exist in version 7. The writer is describing also this file "mazhar-ds.xml" in this directory -> D:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\mmazharhassan.com\deploy\
mazhar-ds.xml.

I would like to ask you what is the difference in newer version or how do I implement this Java Authentication and Authorization Service in JBoss 7 because i can't find any good tutorial for the version 7 (or where do I find all these files).

EDIT: 
 I'm sorry maybe for stupid questions, but I'm complete beginner in this.. :(

Comment: Main difference: JBoss 7 is a Java EE 6 full fledged application server (with all the features of Java EE 6 such as JPA 2, JSF 2, CDI, EJB 3 and more) while JBoss 4 is J2EE 1.4 application server (thus not having all the new power included in Java EE 6).

Comment: JBoss 4 and JBoss7 are essentially completely different pieces of software. Documentation for JBoss4 is of zero value for JBoss 7. And sadly, the documentation for JBoss 7 isn't very good yet.

Comment: What is it you want to do with JAAS? The tutorial you link to isn't actually doing anything with JAAS, it's just doing the basic setup of a database-backed security realm in JBoss.

Comment: I'd like to set up login security on server side, jboss7.. Yes I found out it's very bad documentation, especially for begginers

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a JAAS Module in the same way you did it in JBoss 4, but the configuration of it is different.

What you probably should look at, is the http://docs.jboss.org/teiid/7.2.0.Final/developer-guide/en-US/html/custom_login_modules.html

Especially, the DatabaseLoginModule might be interesting for you.